# why spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion isn’t working in .yml config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I need help on why spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion isn’t working in .yml config. I’d like to set this global property for jackson so that it stops nulls from being returned on our replies.

application.yml file

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  jackson:
    default-property-inclusion: NON_NULL
```

-

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getCustomer", produces =MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> getCustomerList() {
    CustomerSearchReply searchReply = new CustomerSearchReply();
    searchReply.setStatus("200");
    searchReply.setStatusCode("S");
    searchReply.setStatusMessage("Successfull");
    ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<Object>(searchReply, HttpStatus.OK);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

Comment: try defaultPropertyInclusion

Comment: Do you create a new `ObjectMapper` in your code instead of letting Spring Boot configure it? Do you have `@EnableWebMvc` in your configuration? All of these disable auto configuration for the web based parts or the json parts thereof.

Comment: Thank you sir for your quick response. No we didn't created any objectmapper in our code . We tried adding @EnableWebMvc in our code still it didnt worked.